# Why combo box is not loaded from join sql query

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT MainDepartmentsTable.ID, FeesTable.ID,FeesTable.Particular,FeesTable.Fee from MainDepartmentsTable inner join SubDepartmentsTable on MainDepartmentsTable.ID = SubDepartmentsTable.MainDeptID inner join FeesTable on SubDepartmentsTable.MainDeptID = FeesTable.SubDepartmentID WHERE FeesTable.ID = '" & TextDepartmentID.Text & "' ", con)
Dim DataAdopter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable
DataAdopter.Fill(dt)
Load_Deparments()
```

Comment: Firstly, `ComboBoxes` have got nothing at all to do with SQL queries. They are two completely independent things and you need to do your due diligence to find out which one is actually the problem before posting here. Either your query retrieves data or it doesn't? Have you even checked? If it doesn't see anything in the `ComboBox`. If it does then the query is completely irrelevant and the actual issue is in the `Load_Deparments` method that you haven't shown us. Given that you don't actually pass the `DataTable` you just populated into that method, I'm guessing that's exactly the problem.

Comment: Please take a read of http://bobby-tables.com - the SQL you've written there is wide open to SQL Injection hacking, and as a programming habit you should absolutely get out of it now

Comment: @jmcilhinney Load_Departments is another method  but when i run this query it works fin in the sql server and give me the departments but when i run this in the Visual studio it doesnt load the departments to the combo box

Comment: Read what's in the link that Caius Jard posted, you'll need it. Then, how does `Load_Departments` know that you filled a DataTable and what you filled it with? Did you mean to pass that DataTable to the method? Is `FeesTable.ID` actually of type string?

Comment: OK, you just ignored everything I said. Forget the `ComboBox` for now. Check whether the query works first. I would bet money that it does. In that case, the query is irrelevant and you haven't actually shown us the part that is relevant.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can You help me plz i am beginner in vb.net and working on a project

Answer (score 0):

First you need to validate the user input.

`Using` blocks ensure that you connection and command are closed and disposed.

Parameters save your database from sql injection. I had to guess at the datatype.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim DeptID As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextDepartmentID.Text, DeptID) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid department ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
        cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT MainDepartmentsTable.ID,          
                                        FeesTable.ID,
                                        FeesTable.Particular,
                                        FeesTable.Fee 
                                  from MainDepartmentsTable 
                                  inner join SubDepartmentsTable on 
                                        MainDepartmentsTable.ID = SubDepartmentsTable.MainDeptID 
                                  inner join FeesTable on 
                                        SubDepartmentsTable.MainDeptID = FeesTable.SubDepartmentID  
                                  WHERE FeesTable.ID = @DepartmentID;", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DeptID
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Load_Departments(dt)
End Sub

Private Sub Load_Departments(dt As DataTable)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Particular"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Fee"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's an optimization to make setting datasource the last thing you do when binding

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify a bit:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT FeesTable.ID, CoNCAT(FeesTable.Particular, '-', FeesTable.Fee) as DisplayText
FROM 
  SubDepartmentsTable 
  inner join FeesTable on SubDepartmentsTable.MainDeptID = FeesTable.SubDepartmentID
WHERE SubDepartmentsTable.MainDeptID = @id"


Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextDepartmentID.Text)) 'less worried about AWV with ints but read https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)

'this part connects the data to the combo - it's the part you didn't show in your Q and what people are telling you is missing
yourCombo.DisplayMember = "DisplayText"
yourCombo.ValueMember = "ID"
yourCombo.DataSource = dt
```

This isn't intended to be a paste in fix for your problem; you've left out too much info from your question to know how to answer it exactly, so you're gonna have to modify this

Things you need to change:

- The columns that are selected in the SQL - load one column you will show (I demonstrated  how to combine two bits of info under one name of DisplayText) and one column for the backing value (ID)
- The column that is filtered on in the where clause or the name of the text box `TextDepartmentID` - it seems odd to me that a Fee ID should be equal to a Department ID, so I've altered the SQL to retrieve the Fee details for a MainDepartmentID because I've assumed your textbox name is correct and that you intended to show the fees for a department via the subdepartments
- Read the blog linked and perhaps choose adding a parameter in a different way
- Change `yourCombo` to the name of your combobox
- Change DisplayMember and ValueMember setting to match the names of the two columns your SQL query selects
- You only need two columns if youre plumbing up a combo, but if you pass the datatable off somewhere you can add more